# Second order Differ. Eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''=x^2y$$
Let the solution of equation be $y=ke^{f(x)}$
Now differentiating twice and comparing we get
$f'^2(x)=x^2$ so $f(x)=\pm x$

Is this solution and approach right to this question or there is any better and general method ?

Edit:
Thanks Ariana i found my silly mistake .

But In my book it's written that as $y\to \infty $ then the solution of this equation are nearly equal to
$e^{\pm x^2}$ . How that is ?

Comment: $y = ke^x$  does not solve $y'' = x^2 y$.

Comment: Notice $y''=\frac{dy'}{dy}y'$

Comment: Yes, the WKB approximation for large $x$ is $y(x)=Ce^{x^2/2}/\sqrt{x}$. However your derived equation is incomplete, it should be $f''(x)+f'(x)^2=x^2$, which is the associated Riccati equation in $f'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''-xy=0$$
$$y=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\Rightarrow y''=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)a_kx^{k-2}$$
$$2a_2+6a_3x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)-a_{k-2}\right)x^k=0$$
which means: $a_2=a_3=0$
now rearranging we get:
$$a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k-2}}{(k+2)(k+1)}\Rightarrow a_k=\frac{a_{k-4}}{k(k-1)}$$
now go through for $k=4n+i\{i\in[0,3]\}$
and you should get:
$$y=a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4n}}{\prod_{m=1}^n4m(4m-1)}+a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4n+1}}{\prod_{m=1}^n4m(4m+1)}$$
However as you can see, this is not a simple solution

Answer (score 3):

You are facing a special case (the simplest) of the general differential equation
$$y''+(a x^2+bx+c)y=0$$ the solution of which being  [parabolic cylinder functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function) which, after rescaling, lead to Weber differential equations.

For your specific case, the solution is
$$y=c_1 D_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sqrt{2} x\right)+c_2 D_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(i \sqrt{2}
   x\right)$$

In terms of Hermite polynomials, this also write as
$$y= c_1 \,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} H_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x)+ c_2\,
   e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} H_{-\frac{1}{2}}(i x)$$

If you expand as a series
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,x^n$$ you will find $a_2=a_3=0$ and
$$(n+1)(n+2) a_{n+2}=a_{n-2}$$ which implies (identical to @Henry Lee's answer)
$$y=a_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4 n}}{16^n\,n!\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)}+a_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4n+1}}{16^n\,n!\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$